How to add plus 5 hour to the copy Cell and past in other with plus time
I have a script that copies and pastes the value to the blank cell.
Now I have one more issue, the script is the timestamp copy-paste.
How can I add 5 Hours to the time that is copied from Cell?
The date format is 31.01.2024 13:02:34.

This is the code I use for the copy-paste if the cell is blank.
function fill() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = tss.getRange("data!C:C").getValues();

  for(i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];

    if (value == "") {

      var rangeA = tss.getSheetByName("data").getRange(i+1,2);
      var rangeB = tss.getSheetByName("data").getRange(i+1,3,+'0,125');

      if(!rangeA.isBlank()) {
        rangeA.copyTo(rangeB,{contentsOnly:true})
      }
    }
  }
}


From the date format is 31.01.2024 13:02:34, I guessed that your actual cell values of columns "B" and "C" might be the date object. In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
function fill() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // I modified the below script.
  const sheet = tss.getSheetByName("data");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B1:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const timeZone = tss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c || Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss")]);
  range.setValues(values);
}

When this script is run, the value of HH:mm:ss is put into column "C" when column "C" is empty. In this case, the output value uses the format HH:mm:ss.
If you want to use dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss, how about the following modified script?
function fill() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // I modified the below script.
  const sheet = tss.getSheetByName("data");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B1:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const timeZone = tss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c ? Utilities.formatDate(c, timeZone, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")]);
  range.setValues(values);
}

When this script is run, the values are put into column "C" with the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.
If your column "B" includes both date object and string, how about the following modification?
function fill() {
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // I modified the below script.
  const sheet = tss.getSheetByName("data");
  const range = sheet.getRange("B1:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const timeZone = tss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => {
    if (!c && b instanceof Date) {
      return [b, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss")]
    } else if (!c && typeof b == "string") {
      return [b, Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Utilities.parseDate(b, timeZone, "HH:mm:ss") + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss")]
    }
    return [b, c];
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}

If you want to use the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss, please modify the above script.

hi thx the script is good... but not all cell have the date and time some cell have Vacation and some Sick this  give me a error becose it just do date and time ..  what about vacation and sick if cell B have  vacation or sick just copy that to cell C

@John Kater Thank you for replying. About hi thx the script is good, I'm glad your issue was resolved. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your new question but not all cell have the date and time some cell have Vacation and some Sick this give me a error becose it just do date and time .. what about vacation and sick if cell B have vacation or sick just copy that to cell C, I cannot understand it. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the details of your new question? What is Vacation and some Sick?

@John Kater About Vacation and some Sick, if you use my 1st script and in your situation, the texts of Vacation and Sick are put into column "B", how about modifying const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c || Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss")]); to const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c || (b instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss") : b)]);? or : b)]); is : "")]);? If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

i have a script thet work like timestamp on google script for employye and if employye is on Vacation its stamp on google sheet with name in Cell A and add Cell B Vacation if he have not stamp in. my script on top have do it already thet have copy  what ever in cell b to cell c without any modifikation thet i just want thet if cell be have date formate handel it like date and  add 5hour on it if cell b have text value thent handel it like text and just copy and past the value to cell c  i hope u have understand my need....

@John Kater Thank you for replying. About your new question in your reply, I think that my proposed modification can achieve your new question. So, can you test it? Please modify const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c || Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss")]); to const values = range.getValues().map(([b, c]) => [b, c || (b instanceof Date ? Utilities.formatDate(new Date(b.getTime() + (5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)), timeZone, "HH:mm:ss") : b)]);, and test it again.
